# Regex whitespace (\s) handling all spacing types

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm very new to these, but have a regular expression/replace function:

```
string.replace(/\s{10,}/gi, ' ');
```

Because I have a text string that is out of control with a combination of white-spaces, tab spaces, and line-breaks. The problem I am facing is that the above expression handles too much. I have tried dialing it back to `\s{1,}` to alleviate this, but it reduces even line-breaks and tab-spaces down to a single space. I would like to handle those separately with different rules.

It seems like this rule is overriding anything I try to handle the other spacing types.

Comment: What *exactly* do you want your regex to accomplish?

Comment: Do you want to replace just simple blank spaces?

Comment: Please specifically tell us what you want your regex to do. Give examples. If you want a certain group of characters parsed, use the `[]` syntax; put each character you want in the brackets.

Comment: `string.replace(/ +/g, ' ');`

Comment: Specify to us which set of chars do you want to replace. Give us some examples of original string and expected resulting string.

Comment: The `{ }` notation says how many spaces to replace. When you use the form `{n,}` that means "replace all matches of at least *n* repetitions, up to any number". The "g" modifier on your regular expression says to carry out the replacement for every match.

Comment: How about just formatting the string properly to begin with ?

Comment: That is the whole point of `\s`: To handle any *whitespace*. See [Shorthand Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an actual space character to match spaces only:

```
var spaces = / /g; // a valid regex
```

For other types consider these:

```
/\t\r\n/ // other space characters
```